# Not able to find Lennox ML193UH furnace filter

Tags: furnace, filter, lennox

I have a Lennox Merit series gas furnace ML193UH in my attic. The furnace turns on, but no air blows out of it. So i figured the filter needs to be changed. But I'm not able to find it. The pictures show the furnace i have. I have changed the filter for the main air intake vent. Any thoughts on where the furnace filter is??? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Open the clips on the left side of the last picture.  I can't tell for sure in the picture but that looks like a filter holding return vent.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a filter in the return air grille, that's likely the only one in this system. Nobody wants to climb into their attic just to replace an HVAC filter, so when a furnace or air handler is installed in the attic these filter grilles allow placement of the filter in a more accessible location. In fact, according to page 6 of [this spec sheet for that model furnace](https://www.lennoxpros.com/docs/Technical/210588.pdf), a filter rack is not built into this model and is available as an optional accessory.

So unfortunately, something else is wrong with your furnace...

Comment: Thanks!  I'm seeing red light blinking frequency of 3 times which seems to indicate there is an issue with the pressure switch.